# Blazor WASM IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(..) returns client without JWT token in headers

Tags: jwt, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor client app that needs to communicate to multiple API services. In order to simplify things, lets say I have two API servers:

- one API server that handles login and register services (https://localhost:7031/api/...)
- one server that serves Blazor ASP.NET Core hosted app (https://localhost:7030).

Below I show how I configured identity services on 7031 (I am not using Identity Server):

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>(...)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthenticationWithJwt(configuration); // extension method that configures JWT (not shown here)

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddIdentityPolicies();
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .Build();
    });
```

To cut things short, login / register works. Web app is served on port 7030, and authenticates using API's hosted on port 7031. I have also created a test API endpoint with [Authorize] on 7031, to see if I token will be attached to this HTTPS request - all is well. For this to work, I have the following configuration for HttpClient:

```
services.AddHttpClient(
    "IdentityApi",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7031"));

services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("IdentityApi"));
```

So, when I inject HttpClient in some component, it successfully connects to authorized identity APIs. The problem starts when I need to connect to authorized base server APIs (port 7030). In one component I need to access both identity API and server API, so I tried by injecting IHttpClientFactory in it. For this purpose I also added another named HTTPClient:

```
services.AddHttpClient(
    "BaseApi",
    client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)); //"https://localhost:7030"

/* razor component */
var identityClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("IdentityApi);
var baseClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("BaseApi);
```

Both clients have NULL value for DefaultRequestHeaders property. Only if HttpClient is injected directly, then it has DefaultRequestHeaders set, along with Authorization token.

So, somehow this line makes sure that when HttpClient is injected, it has token assigned:

```
services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("IdentityApi"));
```

I tried to use CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler, as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-authorizationmessagehandler-class), but I receive exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider' while attempting to activate 'x.y.z.CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler'.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) ... etc

Anyone knows how can I generate named HttpClients with token assigned?